# What is the correct way to send (Rich Text) Formatted Data via a Web API

Tags: android, json, rtf, android-json

I want to have a (JSON) API (so it is accessible for my Android App) where i can send RTF text.

I want to retrieve text for articles, so it would be very useful if the formatting can also be send this way.

How should i approach this and is JSON even the right way?

Comment: I suggest you to use retrofit library for that.

Comment: Ok, i see that this is handy for dealing with JSON, but can i use it to store the formatted text in JSON?

Comment: So you have string in json format and you want to convert it in json object?

Comment: I realised that i am asking the wrong question. See updated version.